# Elasticsearch match nested field against array of values

Tags: elasticsearch, mongoid, elasticsearch-2.0

I'm trying to apply a terms query on a nested field using [mongoid-elasticsearch](http://github.com/rs-pro/mongoid-elasticsearch) and ElasticSearch 2.0. This has come to be quite frustrating since the trial-error didn't pay off much and the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html#query-dsl-terms-query) on the subject are rather sparse.
Here is my query:

```
  {
    "query": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "awards",
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              { "match": { "awards.year":  "2010"}}
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "nested":{
        "path": "procuring_entity",
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              { "terms": { "procuring_entity.country": ["ES", "PL"]}}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

While "match" and "term", work just fine, when combined with the "terms" query it returns no  results, even thought it should. My mappings looks like this:

```
  elasticsearch!({
    prefix_name: false,
    index_name: 'documents',
    index_options: {
      mappings: {
        document: {
          properties: {
            procuring_entity: {
              type: "nested"
            },
            awards: {
              type: "nested"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    wrapper: :load
  })
```

If "nested" doesn't count as analyzer (which as far as I know doesn't), than there's no problem with that. As for the [second example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html#_terms_lookup_twitter_example),I don't think it's the case since the array of values that it's matched against comes from exterior.
Is terms query possible on nested fields? Am I doing something wrong? 
Is there any other way to match a nested field against multiple values?

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: a shot in the dark could you use lowercase in the terms query example :` ["es", "pl"]` since terms query are not analyzed and it is probably that the data for *procuring_entity* is being analyzed as standard while indexing

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work like that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need to change your mappings for your [nested types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/nested.html) for this - the [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) only works on `not_analyzed` fields. If you update your mapping to something like:

```
elasticsearch!({
    prefix_name: false,
    index_name: 'documents',
    index_options: {
    mappings: {
        document: {
            properties: {
                procuring_entity: {
                    type: 'nested',
                    properties: {
                        country: {
                            'type': 'string',
                            'index': 'not_analyzed'
                        }
                    }
                },
                awards: {
                    type: 'nested'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    },
    wrapper: :load
})
```

I think the query should work if you do that.

Comment: It worked. So one has to explicitly map a field as `not_analyzed` or it will otherwise be analyzed.  Thank you!

Comment: No problem! This behavior can be surprising. Don't forget to select this as the answer, so it shows up resolved for other people.